# Highcharts - last column of polar chart goes outside pane

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Creating a polar chart with Highchart... wish to limit the pane from -90 to 90 degrees. But as you can see the last column goes outside of the pane.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsudrzmc/3/

```
 pane: {
  startAngle: -90,
  endAngle: 90,
  center: ["50%", "95%"],
  size: "175%"
},
```

Is there a fix or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: You can add xAxis.min and xAxis.max for manually setting the min and max of your pane xAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/tsudrzmc/4/

Comment: looks good, though it is strange that there is still a line outside of the pane

Comment: this is small Highchart, bug, you can find information about this problem here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3634